# Redirect when Ajax call GET method to PHP

Tags: php, html, ajax, api, redirect

I have a function login() in Javascripts like this:

```
 function login(){
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/../Toeic/API/APILogin/loginBasic',
            headers: 'Content-Type:application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                email: $('#email').val(),
                password: $('#password').val(),
            }),
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.success === true){
                    $.ajax({
                        method: 'GET',
                        url: '/../Toeic/Source/Home/homePage',
                        beforeSend: (xhr) => {
                            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + getCookie("Authorization"))
                        },
                        headers: {
                            ContentType: 'application/json',
                        },
                        success
                    })
                }
            }
        })
        return false;
    }
```

When **data** return is ***True*** i call a Get method to   ***url***: '/../Toeic/Source/Home/homePage',
with Bearer token in headers. The URL I call will check the Bearer token (JWT) in headers, if not authen then redirect to LoginPage, if success will redirect to HomePage. How can I can call Get method and display the HomePage i want without lost the Bear token in headers

Comment: Maybe I got you wrong, but your problem is, that you lose the auth token after redirect, correct? 
If so, is there anything wrong with localstorage?

Comment: yes, if i using location.href , the headers with Bearer will lost, then I can't not go to the HomePage

Comment: I read on RestfulAPI.com, the api return just data, not return a template or view. I wonder ask how to check Authen into a current page ? For this case, after login success how can I redirect into Homepage with token.Tks a lot